# Azure Service Bus IQueueClient.registerSessionHandler: Unable to consume messages continuously from Queue/Topic

Tags: java, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

***Requirement***: I need to get all the messages from all the sessions from the queue. `registerSessionHandler` should consume messages as soon as they appear in the queue.

***Issue***: the code accepts the messages that are pertaining to one of the session id (xyz) and then it just waits. And even when more messages are pushed with that session id (xyz), it fails to consume it.

> Any suggestions - what obvious thing I am missing here.

I have `registerSessionHandler` for receiving session messages continuously from the queue. Whenever i start new session, i am getting message of only one `sessionID`.

*Test Queue*: In this queue, there are 20 messages available with 4 different sessionIDs. Whenever i run Java application (`QueueSessionReceiveTest.java`), i get only 5 messages which is associated with single session ID.

> MAVEN - azure-servicebus - 1.1.1
>
> RECEIVE CODE:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.IMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.IQueueClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.QueueClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ReceiveMode;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.SessionHandlerOptions;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.ConnectionStringBuilder;
public class QueueSessionReceiveTest {
    private static final String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://XXXXXX";
    private static final String queueName = "test";
    private static IQueueClient queueClient;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        queueClient = new QueueClient(new ConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString, queueName), ReceiveMode.PEEKLOCK);
        queueClient.registerSessionHandler(new QueueMessageSessionHandler(), new SessionHandlerOptions(1, false, Duration.ofMinutes(1)));           
        }}
```

> SESSION HANDLER CODE:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ExceptionPhase;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.IMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.IMessageSession;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.IQueueClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.ISessionHandler;
public class QueueMessageSessionHandler implements ISessionHandler {
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(IMessageSession session, IMessage iMessage) {
        return session.completeAsync(iMessage.getLockToken()).thenRunAsync(() -> Logger.debug("some log") );
    }
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> OnCloseSessionAsync(IMessageSession session) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void notifyException(Throwable exception, ExceptionPhase exceptionPhase) {
        // Do nothing
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link for solution.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues/187